# How to convert NSSet of "Tag" objects with a String field to [String]?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8, ios9

```
var tmpImg = self.dbManager.getPhotoItemById(ptempArr[imageIndex].photoId)

    var nss = tmpImg!.tags // NSet of "Tag" objects with a String "tagName" field

    let arr = map(nss, { "\($0)" })


    customView!.setLabelArray(arr) // I want arr to become an array of tagNames.
```

Ex) Tag objects: {tagName: "tag1"}, {tagName: "tag2"}

I want arr to be ["tag1", "tag2"]

Answer (score 1):

Swifts's `map` function is the way to go. However, you have to be careful with forced unwrapping.

```
let stringArray = tagArray.map { $0.tagName! } // crashes if tagName is nil
```

Safer:

```
let stringArray = tagArray.filter { $0.tagName != nil }.map { $0.tagName! }
```

Comment: I don't think that is necessary in this case.  The OP has an `NSSet` of `Tag` objects and each one has a `tagName`.  The `!` is there because the resulting array was `[String!]` instead of `[String]` like the OP desired.

Comment: No, the OP did not address the potential optionality of the `name` attribute, only that of the `tag` managed object itself. Unless he has unchecked "Optional" in the Core Data model editor before generating the subclasses, the type will default to `String?`.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks @Mundi.  I updated my answer to use the nil coalescing operator.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of this solution as well but then he would have an array with multiple `""`s in it... Probably not desired.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert your `NSSet` of `Tag` objects into `[String]`:

```
let arr = nss.allObjects.map {$0.tagName ?? ""}
```

First call `allObjects` to get `[AnyObject]` and then use `map` to get the `tagName`s.  If a `tagName` is `nil`, the *nil coalescing operator* `??` will replace it with the empty string `""`, otherwise it will be unwrapped.

Or more simply, these work as well in **Swift 1.2**:

```
let arr = map(nss, {$0.tagName ?? ""})
```

or

```
let arr = map(nss) {$0.tagName ?? ""}
```

In **Swift 2.0**:

```
let arr = nss.map {$0.tagName ?? ""}
```